# Does VC-VC communication change with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In the past I would do:

- `MainViewController` pushes `ProfileViewController`

  - In `willPerformSegue`, give the target `ProfileViewController` access to a `profile` instance
  - Also set target delegate to `self`
- `ProfileViewController` allows the user to edit their profile
- User presses save
- `ProfileViewController` calls sends message `didSave` to delegate and pops out
- `MainViewController` handles the `didSave` by saving the model to disk

All of this still works in Swift. My question is: is this still the favored way to handle inter-VC communication in the Swift era?

Comment: IMO yes, most of what swift changed was syntax. Most cocoa core competencies and classes are the same whether doing networking, core data, or anything dealing with MVC. I don't really know any other way to pass data between controllers without creating singletons which imo is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: is this still the favored way to handle inter-VC communication in the Swift era?

With the caveat that the method name is `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, that's fine way to do it, and as far as I know it's still fine under Swift. Apple didn't make any announcement at WWDC 2015 that things have changed in this respect, and the `UIViewController` interface doesn't suggest any more compelling ways to configure a view controller during a segue.

> `MainViewController` handles the `didSave` by saving the model to disk

That's also fine, since `MainViewController` is `ProfileViewController`'s delegate, and it sounds like `ProfileViewController` isn't aware of the entire model. In other circumstances, it might make sense for a view controller to use the model directly, and for the model to handle saving. But that's a design issue, not a Swift vs. Objective-C issue.

Comment: Thanks! My biggest issue was whether delegates are old style and this situation would follow them many others which have replaced delegates with blocks/callbacks.

Comment: It's true that blocks are often used now in places where delegates used to be the only choice. Like delegation, blocks give you a way to customize an object's behavior without subclassing, and particularly when there's just a little customization to be done blocks can eliminate the need to create a whole new class solely to be a delegate. Delegation is probably a better choice when you need to define a set of related responsibilities. There's nothing wrong with continuing the way you are, but if the only thing the delegate does is save, passing a block would also be a fine way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Or rather you can do it the same way.

Swift is just another *language*, which uses the same *libraries*.
Things you describe related to those libraries, the notion of UIViewController is defined within them, so everything is done the same way.

The delegate pattern works well, but it's not the only way to communicate between controllers, and it can't be "best" in all cases. The best way depends on the task you're trying to solve, not the language you use.